# Manually inject service into directive from component

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have directive

```
     @Directive({
      selector:'[appAsyncNameValidator][formControlName],[appAsyncNameValidator][ngModel]',
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => AsyncNameValidatorDirective), multi: true
        }
      ]
    })

    export class AsyncNameValidatorDirective implements Validator {
       constructor(private service: any service that implements IForValidation) {
       }

      validate(c: AbstractControl): Observable<any> {
         return doSomethig(c); // => use in doSomethig service.getByName(c.value) 
      }
    }

export interface IForValidation{
       getByName(name: string);
    }
```

And component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-role',
  template: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="roleName" name="roleName" 
             placeholder="Role name..." [(ngModel)]="role.name" appAsyncNameValidator 
             required #roleName="ngModel">`,
  styleUrls: ['./edit-role.component.scss']
})

export class EditRoleComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

And I want to make this directive generic for all services. How to inject any service into directive from component ?

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface `IRoleService`:

```
export interface IRoleService {
    getRoles(uid:string):Role[];
    ...
}

const IRoleService = new OpaqueToken("IRoleService");
```

Setup the binding of your interface to a concrete class:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [{
         provide: IRoleService,
         useClass: RoleService
    }]
})
```

Inject it like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(IRoleService) roleService:IRoleService).
```

Comment: how do you disambiguate `IRoleService` token and interface?

Comment: I've updated the question. If I have 100 services that implement interface IForValidation, it'll be difficult to resolve dependency. Is it a normal practice to use @Input for any service instead injection ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the OpaqueToken is necessary so that you can bind a token to an interface. i.e. { provide: IRoleService }

Comment: @pixelbits that part is clear. I just don't think using a token and an interface with the exact same name within the same scope will need some way to disambiguate these two.

Comment: It's interesting.  Perhaps its the context with how the token/interface is used that allows it disambiguate the two. It works, regardless.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

I've added next inputs to my directive

```
@Input() service: any;

@Input() methodName: string;
```

And used it like this in my doSomethig(c) method:

```
this.service[this.methodName](value);
```

In component you have to use it in next way:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="roleName" name="roleName" placeholder="Role name..." 

          [(ngModel)]="role.name" appAsyncNameValidator [service]="roleService" [methodName]="'methodName'"

          required #roleName="ngModel">
```

Hope this will help somebody.